# Error : Exception calling "MoveTo" with "1" argument(s): "The server is unwilling to process the request. "

Tags: ou

I am trying to write a script to move OU of users in AD 2008

```
$Alias = "hareeshvm"

# Finding the location of the user account harveesm:

$Root = [ADSI]("LDAP://DC=corp,DC=bharatpetroleum,DC=com")
$searcher = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root)

$searcher.filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(mailNickName= $Alias))"

$User = $searcher.findone()

# Binding the user account to $AUser and the OU to move to to $MovetoOU
$ADSPath = $User.Properties.adspath


$MoveToOU = [ADSI]("LDAP://OU=Temp,DC=corp,DC=bharatpetroleum,DC=com")

$AUser = [ADSI]("$ADSPath")
```

# Command to Do the actual move

$AUser.PSBase.moveto($MoveToOU)

And I am getting below mentioned error

*Exception calling "MoveTo" with "1" argument(s): "The server is unwilling to process the request.
"
At D:\Ashish\MS Exchange\New User\newuserscreation.ps1:39 char:21
+ $AUser.PSBase.moveto <<<< ($MoveToOU)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException*

thx in advance